# How to extract from an array of hash

Tags: ruby

```
people = [
    {id: 101, first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe'},
    {id: 102, first_name: 'Tom', last_name: 'Rogers'},
    {id: 103, first_name: 'Bill', last_name: ''}
]
```

I want to put a list of name like this

```
"John Doe, Tom Rogers, Bill"
```

How can i achieve this is in ruby?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. Then we can see where you fall short.

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
people = [
  { id: 101, first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe' },
  { id: 102, first_name: 'Tom', last_name: 'Rogers' },
  { id: 103, first_name: 'Bill', last_name: '' }
]
```

Code

```
p people.map { |x| x[:first_name].to_s + ' ' + x[:last_name].to_s }
        .map(&:strip)
        .join(",")
```

Output

```
"John Doe,Tom Rogers,Bill"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
people
  .map { |p| p.values_at(:first_name, :last_name).join(' ').strip }
  .join(', ')
#=> "John Doe, Tom Rogers, Bill"
```

or

```
people
  .map { |p| "#{p[:first_name]} #{p[:last_name]}".strip }
  .join(', ')
#=> "John Doe, Tom Rogers, Bill"
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, but I wanted to add a demonstration of string interpolation.

```
people
  .map { |p| "#{p[:first_name]} #{p[:last_name]}" }
  .join(", ")
```

@rajagopalan has a good idea in using `strip` to remove unwanted whitespace at the beginning and end of the first and last name combination, but it might be even better to run this on each component of the name.

```
people
  .map { |p| "#{p[:first_name].strip} #{p[:last_name].strip}" }
  .join(", ")
```

Comment: _"It might be even better to run this on each component of the name"_. Not really because the last entry in the example would look like this then: `"Bill "` (Note the whitespace at the end).

Comment: Good point. Then maybe the right answer is to do both!

Comment: Or perhaps `"#{p[:first_name]} #{p[:last_name]}".sub(/\s+/, ' ').strip` to remove leading or trailing whitespace, and any extraneous whitespace inside each name.

Comment: Extraneous whitespace. `.sub(/\s+/, ' ')` is going to replace one or more whitespace characters with a single space.